# Java AWT.Robot не работает ALT + TAB

Tags: java, windows, awt

Играясь с библиотекой Robot обнаружил что не получается использовать горячую комбинацию ALT + TAB. Гугл говорит что это связанно с тем что у меня Window 8. От сюда возникает вопрос - как можно это обойти? Ну то есть не вариант однозначно писать кликер с точку экрана ибо положение окон всегда меняется. Нет ли другого способа? 
Ну и собственно не работающий на восьмой Винде код:

```
public class MyRobot extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
String time = localTime.toString().substring(0, 8);
try {
  Robot rb = new Robot();
  System.out.println("Start on " + time);
  rb.delay(2000);
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
  localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
  localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
  time = localTime.toString().substring(0, 8);
  System.out.println("Pressed on " + time);
} catch (AWTException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  System.err.println("Robot error on " + time + ". The problem is: ");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```